# Orchestrate BigQueryML Pipeline using Airflow

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, new-operator

The Problem :

The Data are located in BigQuery and I want to create ML model based on these data via BigQueryML APIs (I don't want to use BigQuery UI to create the model), As I see in Google Cloud BigQuery documentation [REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/models) , the following methods are available:

- **Delete:**  Deletes the model specified by modelId from the dataset.
- **get:**     Gets the specified model resource by model ID.
- **list:**    Lists all models in the specified dataset.
- **patch:**   Patch specific fields in the specified model.

but there is no methods to create, train, evaluate a model in BigQuery.

The main purpose of this is to orchestrate an ML pipeline in Apache Airflow using  [BigQuery Hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ddcc84833740a73c6b1bdeaeaf80ce4b354529dd/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L66), since there is no operators available in Airflow support this.

I am thinking about using PythonOperator with client library to implement this but i don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Those operations are plain SQL statements, so you execute them as it was a query.

Answer (score 0):

All SQL queries, including create / evaluate model, can be sent in either query or job apis.
Query API:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

Job API:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfiguration
where use https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery for the query.

Job API is asynchronous and thus recommended if the query takes longer to finish.

Also, Google Cloud Managed Pipeline has BigQuery ML components that you can use directly. To learn more, see https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/bigqueryml-component